# How to send parameters to portlet use jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, portlet

I have a form on my jsp page. In this form i choose a file (zip archive) and after click submmit call servlet to upload this file. For file upload im use Apache Commons FileUlpoad library. After upload im unzip archive. Them i do redict to this jsp.

jsp code:

```
<form action="Upload_Servlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="up">
       <input id="fileUpload1" type="file" name="filename1"value="Browse..."/>
   </div>
   <div>
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Загрузить">
        <input type="button" id="del" onclick="deleting()" value="Удалить">
   </div>
</form>
```

servlet code:

```
public class uploadfile extends HttpServlet
{

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    System.out.println(response.getCharacterEncoding());
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(response.getCharacterEncoding());
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("wtpwebapps<br/>");
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if (!isMultipart) {
        writer.println("<HTML>");
            writer.println("<HEAD <TITLE> Upload4 </TITLE> </HEAD>");
            writer.println("<BODY>");
            writer.println("<FORM action = \"Upload_Servlet\" method = \"post\" enctype = \"multipart/form-data\">");
            writer.println("<INPUT type = file name = ufile>");
            writer.println("<INPUT type = submit value = \"Attach\">");
            writer.println("<h1>its not multipart</h1>");
            writer.println("</FORM>");
            writer.println("</BODY>");
            writer.println("</HTML>");
            return;
        }          
  FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> list=null;
    String mifpath= "1";
    String path = " ";
    String mif = " ";
    String from = "\\\\";
    String to ="/";
    String error="";
     try{
      list = upload.parseRequest(request);
      Iterator<FileItem> it = list.iterator();
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      while ( it.hasNext() ) 
      {

        FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next();
        File disk = new File("C:/uploaded_files/"+item.getName());

            path = disk.toString();

            String code = new String(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."), path.length()).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"utf-8");
            if (code.equalsIgnoreCase(".zip"))
            {
                mifpath=path;
                mif = mifpath.replaceAll(from, to);
                item.write(disk);
                error=unzip.unpack(mif, "C:/uploaded_files");
            }
            else
            {
                error = "Выбранный файл не является архивом zip";

            }
      }
    }
     catch ( Exception e ) {
      log( "Upload Error" , e);
    }
     request.setAttribute("error", error);
     request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp").forward(request, response);

    // String redictedURL="http://localhost:8080/redicted_test/Home.jsp";
    // response.sendRedirect(redictedURL);
    writer.close();
    }
}
```

Now i want to do this on the portal. Its mean that i dont want to reload my jsp after I upload a file. So i have to use Jquery. And i have some questions:

1. How to submit form to use jquery in my case?
2. My servlet code will be work in portlet?
3. How to send parametrs to jps from portlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery it can be done easily:

1. Set a click event on the submit button (or on the form submit).
2. Post data to servlet:

   ```
   $.ajax({
           url : base_url + 'Upload_Servlet',
           type : "post",
           data:$('form').serialize(),             
           cache : false,
           success : function(data) {
               //do some stuff

       },
       error : function(xhr, status, err) {
           //do error stuff
       },
       timeout : 3000
       });
       //End ajax call
   ```
3. After the servlet is done, just use the response writer to write an aswer back (If it contains a lot of data, I'd recommend sending a response in the form of json, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224338/sending-json-data-servlet-applet-communication-example/11225420#11225420)) and then the success callback is called and you can do whatever you like with this data.

**IMPORTANT:** Since you are submitting a form, you need to use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) so the form will not be actually submitted but rather be handeled by your ajax.

Comment: Tnx for anawer. Can you tell me one more thing. What better to use in portlet for fileupload? org.apache.commons.fileupload.portlet or jquery script?

Comment: And what i gonna write in portlet to parse data sended by jquery.

Comment: Regarding the fileupload I've never done it so i don't know. As for json manipulation in java, use Google's Gson. Please mark the answer if you like it.