# Sending JSON data Servlet Applet communication example

Tags: java, servlets, applet

Hi am developing an application in which servlet has to send data(coming from database) to applet i have fallowed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769255/applet-servlet-communication)

it is very useful but they mentioned passing data through JSON can any one give an example of this. I tried serialization of object but am getting 
java.io.EOFException
exception (i searched for solution some one says that may be JVM version miss match lead this) so i decided to go for JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are going to create or read json strings, then I'd recommend using [Google's Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

To send a json response from the servlet do this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write(json);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
```

Comment: This looks good but i have a problem with session. i have set a variable in session and when i open inputstream object in applet it is returning null value

Comment: Seems like you should post another question. If this one helped you please select it as the right answer.