# How do I mutate the DOM of a displayed HTML page, via Java, over HTTP (from the server)?

Tags: java, html, http, dom, servlets

I would like to get a reference to the DOM of a displayed webpage so that I can add and remove elements. I would like to add and remove those elements by sending HTTP requests from, say, a servlet. Further, I would like to be able to construct a DOM, node-by-node, in the browser, via java, from http messages coming from said servlet.

Suppose someone requests a url (say): http://helloWorld.xhtml

I would like to render the content by sending HTTP messages, which, node by node, build the displayed document. Then, if I need to change something in the document, I would like to be able to remove html node-wise, or add html in the same manner; I would like to make partial changes to the html document via http.

Does anybody know of specific way(s) to accomplish this?

I don't want to use JavaScript, unless it means a utility method to accomplish the communication mechanism only. I don't want to use a client-side applet either, but that might be a way of getting around the limitations of http (i.e., sending back java object responses via jaxb).

---

I don't want to use javascript because I just want to use an html browser as a displayer of elements that relay the occurence of events back to the server. Then, I want to be able to add or remove elements without redrawing the page. Also, I would like to use XSLT to generate HTML, but again, I would like a way of updating the web page without using hidden elements and without redrawing the whole page.

I thought of something else also. I might use a JApplet embedded in an HTML page, and then just communicate with the JApplet via JAXB? I am assuming that you can do that.. (maybe it does not work that way). Then, in the JApplet, just using a means of displaying an HTML page; there might be a better option amongst the components than the JLabel.

I think that the best option would either be using the HTTP mechanism (if possible) or else, using some sort of middle layer that would enable me to send Java back and forth between the webpage and the server.

---

I've thought about this a minute, and perhaps, if browsers would change their update policy, then, we would be able to use http to facilitate a view that is updateable on a per-element basis, via a browser behavior that supports additions or subtractions of elements?

Comment: Node by node? That sounds tedious. Maybe Rhino? EDIT: Nevermind, Google Web Toolkit. Can't keep those two straight.

Comment: GWT would still act as a carrier with the client-side JavaScript building out the actual DOM. Whatever server-side component is used, will only act as a sender of messages down to the client, and the client will have to do the actual work.

Comment: @Anurag - Why even let the browser get in the way? I'd say build an extension for, say, Chrome. But that would still probably have some Javascript mucking things up. I guess maybe stream a video of the action on the server? That's what it feels like we're down to.

Comment: javascript is THE web browser DOM manipulation language. use it. just poll the web server, having the server output js to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use JS is beyong me since this is THE language for editing the dom.

The easiest way to accomplish your scenario would be using [Jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

For parsing/building Json i would recommend [Google's Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224338/sending-json-data-servlet-applet-communication-example/11225420#11225420) for a small sample.